# Unable to create symbolic link of compiled executable to my PATH directory

Tags: symlink, path

I've compiled [this build](https://sameboy.github.io/posts/release-0.13.3) of the SameBoy Game Boy emulator with success. However I'm unable to `ln -s` the resulting executable to my PATH directory in `~/.bin/`, as it returns `too many levels of symbolic links: ./sameboy` when I try to execute the symlink.

Comment: What's the exact setup here? That is, where is the symlink, what is its name, and how is its target specified?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the working executable is in `~/sameboy/bin`. So this works just fine, running the game system for you:

```
cd ~/sameboy/bin
./sameboy
```

I suspect this is what you've done to add it to your `~/.bin` directory in your `PATH`:

```
cd ~/sameboy/bin
ln -s ./sameboy ~/.bin    # does not work
```

Unfortunately what this did was create a symbolic link in `~/.bin` pointing literally to `./sameboy`. In the context of the symbolic link this is itself (the link file, not the intended target executable). You can verify this with

```
cd ~/.bin
ls -l sameboy
```

You can fix it by going to your `~/.bin` directory and recreating the symbolic link so it points to your actual executable:

```
cd ~/.bin
rm sameboy                      # your broken symlink
ln -s ../sameboy/bin/sameboy    # relative or absolute path to the executable
```